# Does Assembly.Load loads same assembly every time?

Tags: c#, .net

If I call `Assembly.Load("Example");` 10 times does it load that assembly every time or just once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's loaded just once.

For more detailed information about loading assemblies in different contexts see [Best Practices for Assembly Loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx#load_contexts).